# Animate object on page load, but still be able to change with hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate

Let's say I have a little hover function on three boxes. When I hover over one, it animates and changes the background color. When the page loads, I want one to already be animated. If I hover on another box, it will disappear and then just animate whichever is hovered on.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvtWB/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.box').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "red"
        }, 800);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "green"
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

Now how can animate the middle box when the page loads. Then allow the hover to work as normal (which includes the middle box animating back to normal).

Comment: is the middle box supposed to stay on `'red'` or go to `'red'` and back to `'green'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').eq(1).animate({
        backgroundColor: "red"
    }, 800);
    $('.box').hover(function(){
        $('.box').stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "green"
        }, 800);
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "red"
        }, 800);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "green"
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LvtWB/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('.box').hover(
    function(){

        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "red"
        }, 800,function(){
             $('.box').removeClass('.animated');
        })
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "green"
        }, 800);

    });

})
```

The CSS:

```
 .animated { background:red;}
```

You could experiment with where you want to put the `removeClass`.  It may be better to add a function like the following:

```
$('.box').one('mouseover',function(e){
   $('.box').removeClass('.animated');
})
```

I actually like that better, because it only fires once, but the difference is probably negligible.  You could also take the function off the end of the first `animate`, and stick the line before the `animate` function is called.  My guess is the way I suggested would be the smoothest looking.  But, all ways will work.